# Include filename as tag when importing csv files into influxdb using telegraph

Tags: file, csv, influxdb, telegraf

I'm new to influxdb, and I trying to import some data stored in several CSV files using the telegraf agent and the file input plugin. I wrote a simple file.conf following the instructions in https://dzone.com/articles/write-points-from-csv-to-influxdb, and I was able to import the data into influxdb, both measurements and desired tags with the data inside the files.

I will like to include an additional tag with the name of the file, so I can filter measurements from a specific file, but I didn't found how to do it in the File Input plugin doc (https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/file), neither the CSV Parser doc (https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/parsers/csv).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files plugin does not currently support a method to add a filename tag.  A standardized source tag is in the [process of being added](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/issues/4413) but it is not yet supported by all plugins.  If you would like to see it added to the files plugin, I would suggest opening an issue with the project.

As a possible work around you could add a static tag for each file.  This would require each file to have its own input section in the telegraf configuration file.  Here is an example using a test json log file.

```
[[inputs.file]]
  files = ["./plugins/inputs/file/dev/testfiles/json_a.log"]
  data_format = "json"

  [inputs.file.tags]
    file = "file1"

[[inputs.file]]
  files = ["./plugins/inputs/file/dev/testfiles/json_a.log"]
  data_format = "json"

  [inputs.file.tags]
    file = "file2"
```

**UPDATE**

This feature was [added](http://%20https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/pull/6650#event-2796805370) thanks to your request.  This can be enabled in newer versions of telegraf using the following:

```
[[inputs.file]]
  files = ["./plugins/inputs/file/dev/testfiles/json_a.log"]
  data_format = "json"
  file_tag = "filename"
```

The string value of `file_tag` sets the tag name that will be used to store the file names.

Comment: Thank you NikNye, I realized it was not supported, and I finally included the filename as an additional column when generating the csv file. I will ask for a feature request as I think it can be useful in other scenarios having not control over the file generation.

Comment: @AlvaroMarco I also think this would be a very useful feature.  I've been contributing to the telegraf project and will watch for your request to get the change put in.